# "swing some weight" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> ... One of the guards was eating C rations from a can and reading a comic book.  Garraty watched the guard eating and reading and thought for the ten thousandth time: It's all *real*.  And now, at last, the thought began to ***swing some weight***.  ...

I didn't find the phrase in my dictionary.  What does it mean here?

Comment: http://www.english-slang.com/eng/american/i_s/7800-swing-ones-weight

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks! Is  "swing one's weight" the same as "swing some weight" here? The subject for "swing one's weight" is a person, while "swing some thought" is not a person.

Comment: Appears to be a less familiar version of _throw one's weight around._

Comment: To my mind, only ***conscious agents who have high social standing*** can really ***swing some weight*** (use their influence to make things happen). There are no matches at all in Google Books for [***thought swings some weight***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22thought+swings+some+weight%22) or [***idea swings some weight***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22idea+swings+some+weight%22). But [***idea carries some weight***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22idea+carries+some+weight%22) (appears convincing / plausible) is a perfectly common collocation.